# Caption and keyval conflict in harvard thesis template

Tags: xetex, captions, templates, thesis

I'm trying to compile the harvard thesis template just as it comes from  [here](https://github.com/suchow/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation). I have already all packages in place and have followed the instructions in the readme file including compiling with xelatex. However I keep getting the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: figurewithin undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.448 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{caption}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! Package keyval Error: tablewithin undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.448 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{caption}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

It appears that there is a conflict between the keyval and the caption packages, also a pdf file is generated despite this error. I'm using texlive 2012 on ubuntu 12.10. I'm fairly new at LaTex and have no idea of what is going on and I have not found anything in the forums. I hope someone can explain this to me. Thank you very much.

Another thing is I get exactly the same error when running

```
latex caption.dtx
```

This file can be obtained [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/).

Comment: I get no error from the last command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ProcessOptionsWithKV` will not be used by the `caption` package anymore since 2007/01/30 (which is definitely much older than TeXlive 2012), so I assume you have a strange mixture of old and new packages regarding the `caption` package bundle.

Please take a closer look at the generated log file to see where the different pieces come from. All `caption` related packages should be loaded from the (same) TeXlive directory, and should be of similar age. Here is an example how it should *not* be as `caption.sty` is loaded from the TeXlive directory while `caption3.sty` is be loaded from the current document folder:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)

(./caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/06/17 v1.7-96 caption3 kernel (AR)
```

BTW: The files within https://github.com/suchow/LaTeX-template-for-Harvard-dissertation/tree/master/packages are extremely outdated, even the long-time obsolete ones (like `subfigure`). So please avoid using these package versions.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out the caption package was incomplete, the package consist of sevaral .sty files and I only had one.